# Convert query Teradata to Hive

Tags: hive, casting, case, teradata

i have the following query and it executes successfully in teradata.

```
CASE 
WHEN Cast(STG_101_118_INVM.ACCT_OPEN_DT AS INTEGER) > 2956565 THEN Cast('2999-12-31'AS DATE) 
WHEN Cast(STG_101_118_INVM.ACCT_OPEN_DT AS INTEGER) = 0 THEN Cast('1900-01-01' AS DATE) 
ELSE Cast('1900-01-01' AS DATE) + Cast(STG_101_118_INVM.ACCT_OPEN_DT AS INTEGER) - 1 END 
AS ACCT_OPEN_DT
```

i have the following query and it executes successfully in teradata.
but when run on hive it doesn't work and it shows a warning like this.

```
Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException line 
0:undefined:-1 Wrong arguments 'ACCT_OPEN_DT': No matching method for 
class org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.udf.generic.GenericUDFOPDTIPlus with 
(date, int)
```

what should i change?
can you help me to convert this query to hive format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `date_add()` to add ACCT_OPEN_DT INT to a date. You can use below SQL -

```
CASE 
WHEN Cast(STG_101_118_INVM.ACCT_OPEN_DT AS INTEGER) > 2956565 THEN Cast('2999-12-31'AS DATE) 
WHEN Cast(STG_101_118_INVM.ACCT_OPEN_DT AS INTEGER) = 0 THEN Cast('1900-01-01' AS DATE) 
ELSE DATE_ADD(Cast('1900-01-01' AS DATE) ,Cast(STG_101_118_INVM.ACCT_OPEN_DT AS INTEGER) - 1) END 
AS ACCT_OPEN_DT
```

Comment: but in this section if changed to
ELSE DATE_ADD(Cast('1900-01-01' AS DATE) + Cast(STG_101_118_INVM.ACCT_OPEN_DT AS INTEGER) - 1) END
AS ACCT_OPEN_DT
(use the plus symbol) then the error is still the same

Comment: You are wrongly using `date_add()` . this is how `date_add()` syntax works `date_add(dt_field,  n as INT)`. You must  not use + but use comma. Pls try the SQL i used.